# How to compare 2 dates to obtain whether they are before, same as, or ahead of each other based on quarter?

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 fields of datetimestamp type. I need to compare them based on the quarters those dates occur in and determine whether one occurs in a past, same as, or future quarter.

2 fields: pay.check_dt and pay.done_in_dt. I want to know if pay.check_dt occurs in a prior, same as, or future quarter in comparison to pay.done_in_date
I originally thought to use a case statement converting them using to_Char(fieldname, 'Q-YYYY'), but then I can't to the mathematical comparison because they are then character strings.

Thanks for the help!

Craig

Comment: There are no fields in an Oracle table, there are only columns. Then, there is no *datetimestamp* type - there are two different data types, *date* and *timestamp*. Which data type are your columns? If you don't know, you can run `describe TABLENAME` where `TABLENAME` is the name of your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TRUNC(date)` function: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151)

I have no DB available now, but something like:

```
TRUNC(pay.check_dt, 'Q') < TRUNC(pay.done_in_dt, 'Q')
```

Comment: That works for the which one is past, but I added  a couple bits for after as well   'CASE WHEN TRUNC(pay.CHECK_DT, 'Q') <> TRUNC (pay.done_in_date_DT, 'Q')
    THEN CASE WHEN TRUNC(pay.CHECK_D, 'Q') < TRUNC (pay.done_in_date_DT, 'Q') THEN 'Prior' ELSE 'After' END    
    ELSE 'Current'
    END AS "Prior/Current Qtr" '